# Filtering on asp gridview headers using dropdowns on multiple columns

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

So I tried to added multiple filters for the gridview and I populated the dropdowns with the distinct datas of the column, but it gives me an exception,  System.ArgumentException: Parameter 'siteValue' not found in the collection. I've added the mysql stored procedure along with the below code.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gdvTM" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="gdvTM_PageIndexChanging" DataKeyNames="ID" PageSize="10" CssClass="cssgridview" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#d5d8dc" >
 <Columns >
 <asp:TemplateField   HeaderText="Agent login">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="lbllogin" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("agentlogin") %>'></asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField >
 <HeaderTemplate>
  Site:
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlgvsite" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownChange" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
  </asp:DropDownList>
  </HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="lblsite" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("site") %>'></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:TemplateField>
   <HeaderTemplate>
    Skill:
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlgvskill" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownChange" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
     </asp:DropDownList>
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="lblskill" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("skill") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Shift">
      <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblshift" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("shift") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TM">
      <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lbltm" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("tm") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="GrpM">
      <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblGrpM" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("grpM") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OpsM">
      <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblOpsM" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("opsM") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Leave type">
      <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lbltype" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("leavetype") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
      <ItemTemplate >
      <asp:Label ID="lbldate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("date", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Time">
     <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lbltime" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("time") %>'></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reason" ControlStyle-Width="300px">
     <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="lblreason" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("reason") %>'></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Below would be the server side codes

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGrid();
    }
}
private void BindDropDownList()
{
    TableCell cells = gdvTM.HeaderRow.Cells[0];
    PopulateDropDown((cells.FindControl("ddlgvsite") as DropDownList), (cells.FindControl("lblsite") as Label).Text);
    PopulateDropDown((cells.FindControl("ddlgvskill") as DropDownList), (cells.FindControl("lblskill") as Label).Text);

}

private void PopulateDropDown(DropDownList ddl, string columnName)
{
    ddl.DataSource = BindDropDown(columnName);
    ddl.DataTextField = columnName;
    ddl.DataValueField = columnName;
    ddl.DataBind();
    ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please Select", "0"));
}

private void BindGrid()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStr"].ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(strConnString);
    MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("GetApprovedData");
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    if (ViewState["Site"] != null && ViewState["Site"].ToString() != "0")
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@siteValue", ViewState["Site"].ToString());
    }
    if (ViewState["Skill"] != null && ViewState["Skill"].ToString() != "0")
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@skillValue", ViewState["Skill"].ToString());
    }
    cmd.Connection = con;
    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
    sda.Fill(dt);
    gdvTM.DataSource = dt;
    gdvTM.DataBind();
    this.BindDropDownList();
    TableCell cell = gdvTM.HeaderRow.Cells[0];
    setDropdownselectedItem(ViewState["Site"] != null ? (string)ViewState["Site"] : string.Empty, cell.FindControl("ddlgvsite") as DropDownList);
    setDropdownselectedItem(ViewState["Skill"] != null ? (string)ViewState["Skill"] : string.Empty, cell.FindControl("ddlgvskill") as DropDownList);
}

private void setDropdownselectedItem(string selectedvalue, DropDownList ddl)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedvalue))
    {
        ddl.Items.FindByValue(selectedvalue).Selected = true;
    }
}

protected void DropDownChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList dropdown = (DropDownList)sender;
    string selectedValue = dropdown.SelectedItem.Value;
    switch (dropdown.ID.ToLower())
    {
        case "ddlgvsite":
            ViewState["Site"] = selectedValue;
            break;
        case "ddlgvskill":
            ViewState["Skill"] = selectedValue;
            break;
    }
    this.BindGrid();
}

private DataTable BindDropDown(string columnName)
{
    String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStr"].ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(strConnString);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT " + columnName + " FROM approved WHERE " + columnName + " IS NOT NULL", con);
    MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
protected void gdvTM_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gdvTM.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    this.BindGrid();
}
```

Below would be the MySql stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetApprovedData`
(in  siteValue varchar(45), in skillValue varchar(100))
BEGIN
    select *
    from approved
    where site = siteValue or siteValue is null and 
          skill = skillValue or skillValue is null;
END
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

1) You have to changes your stored procedure like

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetApprovedData`(in siteValue varchar(45),
in skillValue varchar(100))
BEGIN

   IF siteValue IS NULL and skillValue IS NULL THEN 
    select * from approved;

    ELSEIF siteValue IS NULL and skillValue IS NOT NULL THEN
     select * from approved where skill = skillValue;

     ELSEIF siteValue IS NOT NULL and skillValue IS NULL THEN
       select * from approved where site = siteValue;

       ELSE        
       select * from approved where site = siteValue and skill = skillValue;
       END IF; 
END
```

2) In your `BindGrid` function make the changes below

```
private void BindGrid()
{
    //Your rest of code is same here

    string siteValue = null;
    string skillValue = null;

    if (ViewState["Site"] != null && ViewState["Site"].ToString() != "0")
    {
        siteValue = ViewState["Site"].ToString();
    }
    if (ViewState["Skill"] != null && ViewState["Skill"].ToString() != "0")
    {
        skillValue = ViewState["Skill"].ToString();
    }

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("siteValue", siteValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("skillValue", skillValue);

    //Your rest of code is same here
}
```